# Sobre criação e remoção de salas de chat

Tags: suporte, chat

Caros, a base desta pergunta é a resposta que eu dei a esta pergunta aqui:

[Enviar checkbox com ajax jquery php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127824/enviar-checkbox-com-ajax-jquery-php)

Como vêem minha discussão com o usuário Bruno Luz, se estendeu mais do que deveria nos comentários. Estava esperando que o sistema desse a costumeira mensagem "evite discussões longas, quer transferir pra sala de bate-papo?" mas isso não ocorreu.

Inicialmente achei que era porque eu estava usando o App do StackExchange no celular, mas depois, quando cheguei no desktop, vi que também na ocorria.

Então procurei criar uma sala de discussão e ver se conseguia passar a discussão para lá. Mas não tenho prática com salas de chat e não consegui encontrar nem no help, nem no meta como fazer isso.

Depois eu procurei criar uma sala de chat e colocar nós dois para pelo menos podermos conversar a partir dali. Consegui criar esta sala:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39663/discussao-entre-nelson-teixeira-e-bruno-luz

Mas não consegui adicionar o usuário Bruno Luz. Apareceu uma mensagem dizendo que precisa de pelo menos 20 pontos na reputação para usar as salas de chat.

Após isso não consegui apagar a sala que tinha criado.

Pergunto:

- A mensagem de passar a discussão para uma sala de chat não apareceu por causa da reputação do Bruno Luz (16)?
- Seria possível pra mim com minha atual reputação, passar a discussão para uma sala de chat?
- Se não for possível, é uma questão de reputação minha ou apenas dele?
- Não posso passar a discussão para uma sala de chat, nem fazer longas discussões na pergunta. Qual a melhor forma de agir neste caso?
- Como apago a sala que eu criei?

**Edição**

Com base na resposta do JBueno, também estou querendo saber:

- Existe algum método para um usuário com minha rep passar os comentários já existentes para a sala de chat, removendo os mesmos da pergunta ?
- Caso não exista esta função está disponível para usuários com mais rep ou moderadores ? Quanto ?

Comment: Já tive dificuldades semelhantes com o chat no passado. :/ http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1664/como-iniciar-um-chat-com-um-usu%C3%A1rio-fora-do-contexto-de-uma-pergunta

Answer (score 5):

> A mensagem de passar a discussão para uma sala de chat não apareceu por causa da reputação do Bruno Luz (16)?

Sim, ele precisa ter ao menos 20 pontos de reputação para poder entrar em qualquer sala de chat.

> Seria possível pra mim com minha atual reputação, passar a discussão para uma sala de chat?

Desde que o outro usuário tenha 20 pontos, ou mais, sim.

> Se não for possível, é uma questão de reputação minha ou apenas dele?

Apenas dele, como já dito.

> Não posso passar a discussão para uma sala de chat, nem fazer longas discussões na pergunta. Qual a melhor forma de agir neste caso?

Continue comentando, o sistema não te vai te bloquear de escrever novos comentários. Depois que tiverem resolvido o problema, você pode sinalizar os comentários que acha que não agregam valor diretamente a pergunta como **obsoletos** que alguém vai analisar e apagar se for necessário.

> Como apago a sala que eu criei?

Não tenho certeza, mas acho que elas são apagadas automaticamente depois de um certo tempo de inatividade.

Comment: Certo, grato. Mas como faço para passar a discussão para a sala de chat quando um usuário tiver rep pra isso ? Tenho que esperar a mensagem do sistema ou tenho alguma ferramenta onde posso ativamente fazer isso ? Por exemplo, essas discussões aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127039/salvar-dados-em-varias-tabelas/127058#127058 e aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81748/php-tipos-de-arrays-e-valores/81749#81749
Elas já acabaram. Mas enquanto elas estavam acontecendo, se eu quisesse tranferir pra um chat, como faria ?

Comment: Só dizer pro usuário entrar no chat. Cria uma sala e manda o link pra ele.

Comment: ok, mas então não posso eu mesmo transferir os comentários já existentes pra sala de chat, né ? só continuar a conversa lá.

Comment: Isso. Se existe alguma forma de fazer isso antes do aviso do sistema, eu desconheço.

Comment: ok, mais uma vez grato.